# Python pandas HDFstore append dataframe with missing column

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

Say I already have a hdfstore, having 3 columns [a,b,c] whose dtype are [uint32,int64,datetime64[ns]]

**The problem is how to append dataframe with missing column.** Say column 'c' is missing, I try to append only [a,b], I cannot do it directly because the dataframe `cannot match existing table structure`

I try to **reindex** the dataframe including column 'c', and it still doesn't work, because the new column 'c' is all NaN by default, and its dtype is float64, still doesn't match.

So I try to change its dtype, using **.astype(datetime64[ns])** but this method doesn't work on either, the dtype stay unchanged.

Now I am stucked, how can I append this partial column dataframe into HDFstore?